# WCF service works in WCF Client but not in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF service that uses Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent to synchronize a database on an Windows CE device. It works great when I run the service from Visual Studio 2008 but when I host it in IIS (using Windows 10 by the way), the sync fails with a TargetInvocationException. 
If I browse to the service with `http://192.168.1.34:8711/InventoryCacheSyncService/InventoryServiceLibrary.InventoryCacheSyncService.svc` I get the expected "You have created a service." page, but if I use `http://192.168.1.34:8711/InventoryCacheSyncService/WTF` which is the endpoint for the service just mentioned (as well as the url for the client web reference) I get a 404 error - although that url works fine when hosting it in Visual Studio's WCF Test Client. 
I have tried just about every alteration I can think of to the url in the Win CE client but I'm getting nowhere. I'm new to WCF services, so obviously I'm missing something incredible simple. Here's my web.config file:

[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep3Ow.png)

PLEASE help me out if have any ideas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do below steps to host WCF in simple steps

1. Goto Properties of application in visual studio
2. Click on Web tab
3. Select radio button "Use Local IIS Web server"
4. Click on "Create Virtual directory" button

Virtual Directory will be created to your local system.

If want to host WCF in some other server, you can copy same folders to server and can create Virtual directory with same kind of physical path